# Setting and getting in the same SELECT statement, or Complex simple math

Tags: sql, sql-server

My script generates update scripts for the purpose of testing.

In this statement, what I need is something like

```
SELECT 'Update script', @PreviousBalance = @PreviousBalance - @CorrectPrice
FROM table
WHERE column = @Value
```

1. **Order of logic here
2. I have the original balance of an account
3. subtract the transaction amount
4. (generate) insert transaction amount and new balance

   store that new balance as the old balance**

but since '`A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.'` I need some otherway to do this in line. My task is to iterate over some initial value, and update a transactional log. So each time the `@CorrectPrice` must be subtracted from `@PreviousBalance`.

Ideas?

Actual query:

```
SELECT 'UPDATE table 
            SET Amount = ' + CAST(@CorrectPrice as nvarchar(50)) + 
            ', SET CurrentValueUsed = ' + CAST((@PreviousBalance - @CorrectPrice) as nvarchar(50)) + '
            WHERE UsageId = ' + CAST(UsageId as nvarchar(50)) as 'UpdateQueriesToRun'
        FROM table
        WHERE ContractId = @ContractID AND
            DateActive IN (SELECT DateActive
                FROM table
                WHERE ContractId = @ContractID)
        ORDER BY DateActive ASC
```

Comment: I need more explanation than that. I don't follow.

Comment: Are you *required* to collect UPDATE queries using the SELECT statement (like you show in your question)? Or instead of collecting, could you launch UPDATE queries right away?

Comment: I could, but really the question is how do i perform the math that I need to do. I just want to know what values I'm getting, so I came up wwith this hackish test .

How do I change the @PreviousBalance inline?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand the problem, you had to update and save the previous value of your update.

If this is right, you can create a log table with a keyfield field, a date time field (to set when you update value), a feild for the previous balance value and a field with the new balance value.

Then you can create an update trigger on the table you are updating, and with this you can write on the log table the values you are changing.

Hope this solution can help you!